# How to send request and get response for Alexa Voice Service in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, httprequest, alexa-voice-service

Im trying to develop android app that uses Alexa Voice Service, At the moment i'm able to get Access Token for the AVS , also create media player for record audio, and convert it to Byte Array. The problem is when send the request to Alexa I get 204 code. How to overcome this?

```
 public void sendAudio() {
        final MultipartBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("metadata","metadata", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_JSON, generateSpeechMetadata()))
                .addFormDataPart("audio", "audiorecordtest.pcm",
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, streamToSend))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+accestoken)
                .post(requestBody)
                .url("https://alexa.na.gateway.devices.a2z.com/v20160207/events")
                .build();

        System.out.println("REQUEST BODY :"+ request.body().toString());




        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

                final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                System.out.println("STATUS CODE"+ response.code());
                if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT){
                    System.out.println("Successfull! No Content");

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Successfull! have Content" +response.body().toString());

                }


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520950/how-to-integrate-alexa-voice-service-to-custom-android-app

refer to this

Comment: yeah i'm referring that also , but not familiar with these lines.

val items = if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT)
                AvsResponse()
            else
                ResponseParser.parseResponse(response.body()!!.byteStream(), getBoundary(response))